# aws autoscailing os configuration change

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I apply different settings when I expand my server with AutoScaling?

I want to change some settings when I run the AutoScaling extension.
Is there a way to run some of the replicated OS's settings as they change automatically?

Comment: Sorry, but could you please edit your question to provide more details? For example, what do you mean by "AutoScaling extension"? What do you mean by "run some of the replicated OS's settings"? Are you referring to Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling or "Application Auto Scaling"? Thank you.